# Remove categories from post edit page, but keep in sidebar?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, wp-admin

Is it possible to remove the category/taxonomy boxes from the post edit screen, but keep them in the sidebar? It seems like `"show_ui" => true` is the only thing which removes them from the edit page, but this will also hide them from the sidebar.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can hide them in the Screen Options dropdown (which is a per-user basis) if that's what you're looking for:

[image: screen options dropdown]

You could also remove the metaboxes with `remove_meta_box` seen here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_meta_box

So depending on what the HTML ID of that custom box is, you could add a function. Let's say Client Types is `client-types`, then the following should do the trick:

```
function remove_post_custom_fields() {
  remove_meta_box( 'client-types' , 'post' , 'normal' ); 
}
add_action( 'admin_menu' , 'remove_post_custom_fields' );
```

That would hide it for all users in the Post screen.